# Remove all controllers from all stacks

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have an iOS app with multiple(4) navigation controllers with their own root.

structure is:

> NavController (root: Login)
>
> --> TabBarController (Home) - (Search) - (Profile)
>
> ------> NavController (root: Home)
>
> ------------->TableController
>
> ----------------->DetailController
>
> ------>NavController (root: Search)
>
> ------>NavController (root: Profile) (logout button here)

When I am in on of these `navigationcontrollers`(namely `Profile`), there is a logout button that should take me to the initial login screen, how can I make sure that all controllers from all navigation stacks have been removed before loading the login?

I have tried `poptorootviewcontroller` but that will just be the profile page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSNotificationCenter` to handle this.

When the user logs out, post a local notification to your app using:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kLogOut", object: self)
```

Then in each tab's root view controller, register to listen for that notification, and implement the selector function:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.logOutNotificationAction), name: "kLogOut", object: nil)

func logOutNotificationAction() {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```